# Parsley.js 1.x - Error when form data attributes are changed on the fly

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

My Parsley error message on the first keyup event when typing into field `#myTestField`is

> This value is too short. It should have **4 characters** or more.

I tryed to change Parsley field data attributes on the fly, but it seems this doesn't work. It keeps the value assigned in first place (html form) without taking in account the modified one in the JS code.

On Chrome I can check that the data attribute value is changed after the DOM is loaded.

My code is

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myTestField" id="myTestField" data-trigger="keyup" data-minlength="4" data-validation-minlength="0" >
    <button id="mySubmitButton" type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>

<script>
// wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // destroy
    $('#myForm').parsley('destroy');
    // change attribute
    $('#myTestField').attr('data-minlength','2');
    // assign parsley to do the job
    $('#myForm').parsley();
      });
</script>
```

I am doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

This is a known issue of Parsley.js and theres a [Issue #52 on GitHub](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/52)

I also tried to use `removeItem()` followed by `addItem()` on the same input #Id but didn't work either.

I'm still trying to figure out a workaround

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsley is based on data attributes, that are binded by jQuery with `.data()`

Unfortunately, when you add a data- attr, it is not binded to jQuery `.data()`. You'll have to add the validators this way on the fly:

```
<script>
// wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // destroy
      $('#myForm').parsley('destroy');
      // change attribute
      $('#myTestField').data('minlength', 2);
      // assign parsley to do the job
      $('#myForm').parsley();
    });
</script>
```

I'll add an API to add / edit / remove validators on the fly, without having to call destroy :)

Comment: Thx for the clean answer. It works like a charm and i've learned about the jQuery.data()

Comment: Just to know. In 1.1.11 I've added functions to properly add/edit/remove validators. Better than using data() directly;

Comment: I was still having trouble with parsley trying to change the constraints of fields on the fly. So, I used this trick and it works well for me; I'm simply trying to change what fields are required based on values the user selects in a select box.

Comment: hi @guillaumepotier I was try to add required on fly like this $('#admission_no').attr('required', 'true'); but its not working... any other way to archive

Comment: Has there been any progress on this? I've tried just about every example I can find from destroying the form (which is not ideal) up to trying to use refreshConstraints, removeContraints, etc.