# parsley js updateConstraint method

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I'm trying to do a updateConstraint in Parsley.js. 
el.parsley( 'updateConstraint', { cardcheck: "true" }, "MESSAGE NOW" );

According to the plugin it has a method called updateConstraint. That has 2 paramaters. The first one works but the second one the most important one to change the message does not.
When I pass it in after the constraint object it always shows as undefined. Am I passing it incorrectly.

```
   /**
    * Dynamically update an existing constraint to a field.
    * Simple API: { name: requirements }
    *
    * @method updtConstraint
    * @param {Object} constraint
    */
    , updateConstraint: function ( constraint, message ) {
          console.log(" updateConstraint = ", constraint, "   message = ",message);
      for ( var name in constraint ) {
        this.updtConstraint( { name: name, requirements: constraint[ name ], valid: null }, message );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is a bug in code, i have filled bug request with ugly fix:  [parsley() not passing params whe calling functions](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/324)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and easy answer, see what guillaumpotier [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14709267). Destroy parsley, modify the inputs, then initialize parsley again; here is his code:

```
// destroy
$('#myForm').parsley('destroy');
// change attribute
$('#myTestField').data('minlength', 2);
// assign parsley to do the job
$('#myForm').parsley();
```