# ParsleyJS - Display Required Field depending on Select Value

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am most of the time stuck building web applications or SMBs. But I have my days working on front ends. One interesting JS library I recently met is `Parsley.js` for web form validity check. Really cool.

In a new project I am working, I decided to use Parsley, and am not sure how to do this.

I got a select box with two options, `Yes`, `No`. If `Yes` is selected, I need to show the user a text-box that is required.

I went through `Parsley` documentation nearly twice, but couldn't figure out a way. But I think this kind of forms are common and should be supported by Parsley.

Is it possible through `Parsley.js`? Would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done , just need to check your select box selected value, if is 'Yes' then add

```
$( '#field' ).parsley( 'addConstraint', { required: true } );
```

if the value is 'No'

```
$( '#field' ).parsley( 'removeConstraint', 'required' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with this like I did, see what guillaumpotier [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14709267). Destroy parsley, modify the inputs, then initialize parsley again; here is his code:

```
// destroy
$('#myForm').parsley('destroy');
// change attribute
$('#myTestField').data('minlength', 2);
// assign parsley to do the job
$('#myForm').parsley();
```