# How do I dynamically make a field required with ParsleyJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

I'm using Parsley 2.0.4-rc4 for form validation. I have a select field that is by default hidden (set to `display: none;` in CSS), but if another radio field is set to "Yes", this value is no longer hidden and becomes required.

I have a custom validator for the hidden field, but the validator is not getting called when the field is empty.

Things get more complicated because I'm using [bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) for the hidden select field, so I'm wondering if the required `multiple` attribute is interfering with Parsley's DOM API.

What happens right now is even though the field is getting validated when I change its value, when the field is blank and `parsley().validate()` gets called, no validation occurs and the error message that the field is required is not shown. The field is correctly optional when the dependent field is set to "No". I can also confirm that the validator is getting called on field value change.

What I'd like to happen is for the field to warn the user that the field is required when the dependent field is set to "Yes" and the select field is left blank.

I'm using the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678553/parsley-js-error-when-form-data-attributes-are-changed-on-the-fly/14709267#14709267), but I'd like to find a way that doesn't involve destroying the form every time I change the visibility of a field.

Here's the hidden form field:

```
<select id="completed-grades" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple"
        data-parsley-completedgrades
        data-parsley-trigger="change"
        data-parsley-group="block1" >
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
</select>
```

Here's the validator code:

```
window.ParsleyValidator
  .addValidator('completedgrades', function (value) {
    var childAttendedSchool = $('#three-ac-yrs-yes').val();
    return !(childAttendedSchool === 'on' && value.length === 0);
  }, 59)
  .addMessage('en', 'completedgrades', 'At least one grade must be selected.');
```